# Typescript Angular2 Typings d.ts in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, definitelytyped

Quite possible that I am really missing something. But for the life of me I can not get typings to work for Typescript + Angular2. Not with `///` per file nor for the entire workspace. I have tried manually grabbing the source of angular2 off github and putting in a `/typings` directory within the workspace. I have tried using `tsc` to install angular2 typings I have tried the `tsd.json` file that [Badal in this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445936/compile-angular2-ts-file/30446990#30446990) was nice enough to post. But no matter what Vscode continues to say `Cannot find module <blerg>` (ie. angular2/core, angular2/common, etc...) And its driving me nuts!

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is already an extension for installing `.td` directly from VS CODE. Besides that the Angular definitions are shipped with the Angular2 package from npm:

```
npm install angular2
```

The npm package already gives you the definitions. You need to configure your Typescript with:

```
--moduleResolution node
```

Comment: if you use tsconfig.json you need to add `"moduleResolution": "node"` under `"compilerOptions"`

Answer (score 1):

> But no matter what Vscode continues to say Cannot find module

You probably forgot to restart vscode after following the basic guide.

```
npm install angular2
tsc -init
code .
```

Comment: code ? here stands for what ? me too facing the same problem

Comment: basarat There is no basic guide I ever saw. Btw. I figured it, I assume you meant `tsd init` and not `tsc -init` correct? Believe me I restarted vscode twenty thousand times. `code` is not on my path though so that does me no good, but thank you!

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971053/how-to-open-visual-studio-code-from-the-command-line-on-osx) for getting `code` on the command line.

Comment: No worries. I did mean `tsc -init`. It creates a `tsconfig.json` file