# Angular2 How to tsc compile

Tags: angular, tsc

Hi I am trying to tsc compile my project. Currently, it's not automatically tsc compiling. What should I add to my package.json to successfully tsc compile?

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "project1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve -H 0.0.0.0",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng serve",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
```

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445936/compile-angular2-ts-file

Comment: if you want to use the `tsc` script in your `package.json`. Just do `npm run tsc`